# Extracting vertex coordinates from an automatically laid out graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a `Graph` with an automatically computed layout (i.e. not explicitly given `VertexCoordinates`, but using a `GraphLayout` method), how can we extract the coordinates of the vertices?

```
In[]:= g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
Out[]= << picture of graph >>

In[]:= PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates]
Out[]= Automatic (* <-- I'd like to have a list of coordinates here *)
```

It's possible to convert the graph into a graphics object using `Show` and extract the coordinates from there.  Is there a less hacky, more direct/robust way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In version 8, you can use:

```
VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]
```

`AbsoluteOptions` is usually a good bet when other things just return `Automatic`

In version 9, there's the [`GraphEmbedding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphEmbedding.html) function:

```
GraphEmbedding[g]
```

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps:

```
Table[PropertyValue[{g, n}, VertexCoordinates], 
  {n, 1, VertexCount[g]}]

(* 
{{1.93552, 0.76408}, {2.51085, 1.17051}, {1.48194, 1.6304}, {1.90242, 
 1.64263}, {0.92823, 1.47388}, {2.31252, 0.126716}, {0., 
 1.08036}, {1.42818, 0.}, {0.554302, 0.210118}, {1.37128, 0.758598}}
*)
```

Comment: Is there some way to get all values at once using what one would expect `PropertyValue[{g, _}, VertexCoordinates]` to do?

Answer (score 0):

From version 11.3 on, there is also `ResourceFunction["VertexCoordinateList"][g]`