# Separating disconnected graph objects without losing vertex coordinate assignments

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Say I have a graph `Gtest`, which has multiple disconnected components.  I found that I can isolate individual components while retaining vertex coordinate specifications if I use `VertexDelete` in the manner of:

```
VertexDelete[Gtest, ConnectedComponents[Gtest][[2]]]
```

Here assuming that `Gtest` has only two connected components.  However, this seems like a ridiculous way of proceeding.  Is there a one-liner that will let me make a list of graphs `Glist = {g1, g2, g3, ...}` where each $g_i$ corresponds to a particular connected graph in `G`?  How can I do this while respecting my original vertex coordinate assignments for `G`?

Answer (score 3):

A more straightforward way is to use `SetProperty` on the resulting graph to restore the original vertex coordinates.

```
g = Graph[{2 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 5 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 1 -> 7, 2 -> 7},
          VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];
coord = Thread[VertexList@g -> (VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions@g)];
g2 = VertexDelete[g, {5, 1}];
g3 = SetProperty[g2, VertexCoordinates -> (VertexList@g2 /. coord)];

Grid[{{"original", "{5, 1} deleted", "coordinates restored"}, {g, g2, g3}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee `VertexDelete` will preserve `VertexCoordinates`. However you can use `Subgraph` and manually provide the old coordinates:

```
connectedSubgraphs[g_Graph] :=
 Module[{
   vc = Transpose[{
           VertexList[g],
           VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]}]
   },
  Subgraph[g, #,
     (* Exctract the coordinates for vertices in the component *)
     VertexCoordinates -> Cases[vc, {v_ /; MemberQ[#, v], c_} :> c]
     ] & /@ ConnectedComponents[g]
  ]
```

If you have v9 you can use [`GraphEmbedding` to get the coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14583/extracting-vertex-coordinates-from-an-automatically-laid-out-graph/14584#14584) instead of `AbsoluteOptions`

Note that this wont preserve any other options:

```
g = Graph[{
    10 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 11 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
    12 \[UndirectedEdge] 13, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 10,
    1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,
    4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6,
    7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 9},
   VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green},
   VertexSize -> {1 -> Large}];
connectedSubgraphs[g] // Row
```

[image: graphs]

But it can be extended as is shown in
[Preserving labels when using graph functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15655/preserving-labels-when-using-graph-functions)

Disclaimer: I don't know if `ConnectedComponents` and `Subgraph` always preserve the vertex order, if they don't the subgraphs will be given incorrect coordinates.